# Svg anomation rotate is not fixed

Tags: css, animation, svg, rotation

I have a svg that is rotate around a image. But when i zoom out or resize the browers is move. How i make to be fixed?I use the rotate animation and the svg has position absolute.The svg is rotate correct until o resize the window and is not stay fixed.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve] so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I add another post with my example.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61685606/i-have-one-svg-that-is-rotate-around-a-svg-but-is-not-fixed