# I have one SVG that is rotate around a svg but is not fixed

Tags: css, animation, svg, rotation, fixed

```
 <!--BG Photo-->

   <div class="pic1"><img src="1.svg"></div>

   <!--SVG that will rotate-->

    <div class="pic2"><img src="img/vec/gz4.svg" alt=""></div>


.pic1 img{/*Bg Photo*/

   width: 100%;

   height: auto;

   top: 0;

   left: 0;

}
.pic2{

   position: absolute;

   transform: translate(45px,-75px);

}

.pic2 img{

    transform-origin:center;

    width: 50px;

    height: 50px;

    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;

}

@keyframes rotation {

    from {

      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {

      transform: rotate(359deg);

    }

  }
```

The problem is what when i zoon out/in or resize  the brower .pic2

is moving not stay fixed on his original point

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is right yet both SVG images will adjust to the proportion of the available space (do you have only viewBox defined in them, removing the height and width attributes?). So the second image (pic2) will always "bounce" when resizing (but how many web users really do that?).

Maybe define styles for both SVGs in their DIV parent (or "container" element if you wish) by using vw and vh units - instead of pixels, possibly percentages as well - and this will at least give you more predictable result:

```
<style>
body {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;      
}
.pic1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
.pic1 img{/*Bg Photo*/
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.pic2{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translate(2.5vw,88vh);
}
.pic2 img{
    transform-origin:center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
</style>
<body>
    <!--BG Photo-->
    <div class="pic1"><img src="1.svg"></div>
    <!--SVG that will rotate-->
    <div class="pic2"><img src="img/vec/gz4.svg" alt=""></div>
</body>
```